# Arreglar containers para que :hover funcione (debería mostrar una imagen en el respectivo container)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Esta es mi primer página web, estoy intentando hacer que muestre una imagen cuando paso el mouse por encima del container (en cuestión), pero se ve que hay algún error en cómo los dispuse. Me los toma como si fuera uno solo, cuando en realidad yo le indiqué al código que eran tres distintos.
Si es necesario agregar las imágenes al post, me lo indican.
[image: prototipo]

pero se produce esto cuando lo hago en mi código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrían ayudar a resolver ese problema? Este es mi HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;1,200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@4"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="home">
        <div class="headline">
            <header>
                <img src="logo.png" id="titulo">
            </header>
        </div>

        <nav> 
              <ul id="menu" class="no-bullets">
                <li>home</li>
                <li>services</li>
                <li>proyects</li>
                <li>contact</li>
              </ul> 
        </nav>

        <p id="frasesita">  <span class="punchline"> Creativity <br> made simple. </span> </p>

        <img src="punto1.png" id="punto-pintado">
        <img src="punto2.png" id="punto-vacio">
        <img src="punto2.png" id="punto-vacio2">

    </section>

    <section id="services">

        <h1 id="titulo2"> services </h1>
        
            <div id="container1">
                <p id="disenio-titulo" class="secondary"> graphic <br> design </p>
                <div id="linea">
            </div>

            <div id="container2">
                <p id="web-titulo" class="secondary"> web <br> development </p>
                <div id="linea">
            </div>

            <div id="container3">
                <p id="comm-titulo" class="secondary"> community <br> management </p>
            </div>
        
    </section>

    <script>
        ScrollReveal().reveal('.headline');
        ScrollReveal().reveal('.tagline', { delay: 500 });
        ScrollReveal().reveal('.punchline', { delay: 500 })
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

y aquí el css:

```
`

body{
       background-color: #333132;
    }
    
    html, body {
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
    }
    
    #home {
       padding-top: -100px;
       height: 100%;
       width:100%;
       background-image:url(fondo1.png);
    }
    
    .no-bullets {
       list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    #menu{
       margin-right:150px;
       margin-top: -65px;
       font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
       color:white;
       display: flex;
       padding-right: 40px;
       justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    
    li{
       padding:30px;
    }
    
    #titulo{
       padding-top: 130px;
       padding-left: 200px;
    }
    
    #frasesita{
       font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
       font-size: 100px;
       color:white;
       margin-left: 200px;
       margin-top: 150px;
    }
    
    #punto-pintado{
       margin-left: 200px;
       margin-top: 50px;
    }
    
    #punto-vacio, #punto-vacio2{
       margin-left: 20px;
       margin-top: 50px;
    }
    
    #punto-vacio2{
       margin-left: 20px;
       margin-top: 50px;
    }
    
    #services{
       height: 100%;
       background-color: #333132;
       width: 100%;
    }
    
    h1 {
       font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
       color:white;
       font-size:50px;
       margin-top: 130px;
       padding-left: 200px;
    }
    
    .secondary{
       margin-top: 450px;
       margin-left: 210px;
       font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
       color:white;
       font-size:50px;
    }
    
    #linea{
       display:block;
       border-left: 2px solid white;
       height: 450px;
       margin-top: 110px;
       margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    #container1 { 
       display: flex;
       justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    
    
    #container2 { 
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       margin-left: -180px;
    }
    
    #container3 { 
       display: flex;
       justify-content:flex-end;
       margin-left: -180px;
    }
    
    #container1:hover {
       width:34%;
       height: 580px;
       background-image:url(disenio.png);
    }
    
    #container2:hover {
       width:4%;
       height: 580px;
       background-image:url(web.png);
    }
```

`
Reitero, sé que el problema está en alguno de los containers y cómo los creé.

Desde ya, muchas gracias y disculpen si el código es muy malo. Es mi primer página.

Comment: Creo que se debe a que tu inicialmente no le tienes asignado en CSS un ancho a los contenedores, por lo tanto, antes de hacer hover los contenedores se distribuyen de manera correcta, pero cuando le pones el hover estas cambiando los anchos de manera incorrecta, es decir, que clase de contenedor tendria como ancho un 4% si quieres mostrar una imagen?, ese tipo de preguntas no me dejan dormir en la noche xd, pero bueno, realmente es mas sencillo de lo que parece, simplemente debes arreglar los anchos de los container.

Comment: Por cierto, esos `margin-left` que tienes creo que tambien pueden afectar en algo.